Permission Denial: android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED
I'm getting below error while sending a broadcast event.
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED

I've already provided all the required permissions in the manifest too but unable to fix it.
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false" />

I'm registering in activity as:
private fun setBluetoothReceiver() {
        val filter = IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)
        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED)
        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED)
        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED)
        registerReceiver(bluetoothReceiver, filter)
    }

And sending Broadcast from the onReceive function of the Broadcast Receiver as:
val local = Intent()
                    local.setAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED)
                    local.putExtra("number", device.name)
                    if (context != null) {
                        context.sendBroadcast(local)
                    }

Why is this happening?

"I've already provided all the required permissions in the manifest" -- I recommend that you edit your question to show how you followed the complete instructions for listening to this broadcast. In particular, please show where you are requesting BLUETOOTH_CONNECT at runtime, in addition to having it in the manifest.

I'm requesting these actions while registering the broadcast.

Great! However, none of that shows that you followed the instructions to request the BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission at runtime, as is covered in the documentation. This would be code using ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission to request the permission, such as is shown here.
